# What GCC flags are used by major open-source projects to control undefined behavior in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, undefined-behavior

There are a handful of GCC flags that are used by major open-source projects to work-around perceived over-eagerness on the part of the compiler when handling undefined behavior, specifically in the C and C++ languages. For example:

- -fno-strict-aliasing is a staple for those who want "traditional" behavior when type punning. For example: https://lkml.org/lkml/2003/2/26/158
- -fwrapv is commonly used when wanting to have known behavior for signed overflow. For example: http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2005-12/msg00635.php

What other ones are there? I obviously can get the full list from the GCC documentation of what flags turn what undefined behavior into what kind of implementation-defined behavior. However, I'm more interested in which options are used by major open-source projects and *why*?

Comment: You mean like `-Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Weffc++ -Wstrict-aliasing -ansi -pedantic -Werror -Wunreachable-code` to show all the warning for undefined behavior and making them errors.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable. How do you define "commonly used?" Commonly used by whom? For what purpose? Etc.

Comment: I think commonly used might be interpreted as "How do most of you do this?"

Comment: What @Nicol said. If you don't want _facts_, but _prevailing opinion_, then you're in the wrong place. SO is not a forum.

Comment: @Loki the -W options don't change how the compiler turns undefined behavior into implementation-defined behavior. I gave two good examples of what I'm talking about with example references to discussions about them on real, major projects (the Linux kernel and Postgres).

Comment: I don't want *opinion* on commonly used, but *data* about if they are *actually* commonly used. I'll edit to say this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Wouldn't this be a perfect example for a *community wiki* post?

Comment: @Lightness I absolutely only want facts, not opinions. See my comments and my edit that clarifies this!

Comment: @Nicol I updated the question to remove "commonly-used" and instead referenced "major open-source projects" which is the main data point I am trying to get.

Comment: @bitmask: There have not been community wiki questions for ... months and months.

Comment: @wjl: Then it comes down to no prior research, since you can gather that data yourself quite easily.

Comment: @Lightness the facts about which options are used by major open-source projects (what I originally meant by "commonly used") is not answered in the GCC manual. That's why I stated in my original question that just referring to the manual is not helpful.

Comment: @Lightness I tried to gather data. As you see, I gave two examples and links to discussions about them by the projects in my question. I spent about 2 hours researching this, but thought I could find help by asking here, as generally SO is a GREAT place for this kind of info. Sorry if I touched a nerve. =)

Comment: @wjl: That doesn't really help. A survey of the compile flags for "major open source projects" is a poll. And what constitutes a "major" project? Notice that the question has already attracted 2 answers that completely miss the point. So no, I don't see this as being an improvement.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: So what? Because there hasn't been a cw question for a long time means there's never going to be one again? A quick search on meta didn't show any hints that cw is discouraged.

Comment: @Nicol you are right, the answers so far missed the point, as has apparently just about everyone leaving a comment, so maybe this question is doomed. If it's my fault, I apologize, but I thought I asked a very clear question with examples of what I'm looking for as answers.

Comment: @bitmask: No, the feature has been removed. So good luck with that.

Comment: @wjl: _You_ missed the point; the question was clear, but it's not on the right website.

Answer (score 4):

-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG is not exactly a compiler flag but it enables checked STL iterators and other goodies.

```
std::vector<int> v(42);

v[42] = 1; //The standard says this is UB. With checked iterators you will get a run-time exception.
```

Answer (score 3):

Personally the most important one is:

- -Werror

This forces me to fix all warnings (as warnings are really logical errors).

Then I try and turn on as many of the default warnings with:

- -Wall
- -Wextra

To force myself to standards comliand and thus make the code as portable as possable

- -pedantic
- -ansi

I like S.Myers books so I add

- -Weffc++

But unfortunately not all the libraries I use work well with this. So I turn it off a bit.

Comment: +100 for -Werror. Look at every warning people. Fix them all. If it is a genuine false alarm, `#pragma` it out. One warning in the build log is one warning you have ***ignored***, or it wouldn't be there. (You rebuilt to check they were all gone, didn't you?)

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yep. Flip answer to bad question. I hope it is useful to somebody.